# Python Pandas Data frame Pivoting

Tags: python, pandas

I have such .txt file:

| Field | Value |
| --- | --- |
| First | 1 |
| Second | alfa |
|  |  |
| First | 23 |
| Second | beta |
|  |  |
| First | 55 |
| Second | omega |

I need to read and transform this file to get data like this:

| First | Second |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | alfa |
| 23 | beta |
| 55 | omega |

I start with this:

```
file = './data.txt'
df = pd.read_csv(file, sep='\t',header=None, skiprows=89, skipfooter=11, engine='python')
df = df.pivot(values=1, columns=0)
```

but it looks as I need to generate some indexes otherwise my pivoted table  looks not very well

| First | Second |
| --- | --- |
| 1 |  |
|  | alfa |
| 23 |  |
|  | beta |
| 55 |  |
|  | omega |

Is any other solution hot to read that data and get the results that I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is you need to create common keys for the index.
Using [.assign](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) create a column named CommonKeys which is the [cumcount](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) of grouping on the Fields column. Finally chain functions to pivot and clean up the df.

```
df = (
    df.assign(CommonKeys=df.groupby("Field").cumcount())
    .pivot(index="CommonKeys", columns="Field", values="Value")
    .reset_index(drop=True)
    .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
  First Second
0     1   alfa
1    23   beta
2    55  omega
```

Answer (score 0):

in order to make your code work I had to modify the way you access the .csv file, as I don't have that many rows.

```
import pandas as pd

file = './data.txt'
df = pd.read_csv(file, sep='\t',header=0, engine='python')
df = df.pivot(values='Value', columns='Field')

# for each column on the dataframe, sort the value and ignore the index
for col in df.columns:
      df[col] = df[col].sort_values(ignore_index=True)

# drop NaN
df.dropna(axis=0, how='all', inplace=True)

# Show dataframe
print(df)
```

Here some more info about .sort_values:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html

Hope it can help :)